# Creating a multidimentional array from a flat JSON file

Tags: json, node.js, multidimensional-array

Firstly, I'm very new to nodeJS... like day 5. So bear with me.

I'm building an FAQ app to get into it and I have written a controller and a model which is returning this JSON file:

```
[
    {
        faq_id: 1,
        faq_question: "This is a question?",
        faq_answer: "And a lovely answer",
        tab_title: "Tab title here",
        tab_id: 1
    },
    {
        faq_id: 2,
        faq_question: "Another question",
        faq_answer: "With an answer",
        tab_title: "Tab title",
        tab_id: 2
    }
]
```

}

The requirements are that all the questions are categorised into tabs on the FE. So two tables, one for tabs and one for faqs.

Where each question has an appropriate tab_id associated with it to make the relationship.

What I need to do is create top level nesting in the JSON file to be all the tabs, then iterate over the questions and match the faq_tab_id with the tab_id and nest the question into the appropriate tab.

I have started with looking into using an UnderscoreJS map?

Not sure how much sense it makes or if any more code would be required, but any advice would be welcome. I'm not clued up on the terminology yet so I struggled to find an already asked question to do something like this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you intend to do, [Underscore.js groupBy function](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) may be enough:

```
// This will group the objects by their 'tab_id' property
var grouped = _.groupBy(myData, 'tab_id');
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look into this now. 

Comment: You sir... thanks! I was a bit lost on the track of thinking that their map function would do what we need.